# How to host two or more Websites on one Virtual instance in Google Cloid

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, virtualhost, litespeed

I have :

1. Set up a openlitespeed-wordpress-1-vm package on a virtual instance of a google compute engine. This installs the following softwares :

Operating System
Ubuntu (20.04)
Software
WordPress (5.4.1)
PHP (7.3)
OpenLiteSpeed (1.6.13)
phpMyAdmin (5.0.2)
MariaDB (10.4)
Redis (5.0.7)
Memcached (1.5.22)
CertBot (0.40.0

2. Setup a Wordpress site on above and migrated one of my existing Wordpress websites ( say [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) ) to it.

Now , on the SAME virtual instance, I want to install ANOTHER wordpress Website ( say [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com) ).

How can this be done ? All pointers, weblinks etc. will be MUCH apreciated. I am a computer newbie but can do basic tasks such as running linux commands etc.

Thanks for all help !

Answer (score 1):

Doc is [here](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/wordpress/#how-do-i-create-additional-virtual-hosts).

If you launch the VM from the 1click/Marketplace, then here's an example for you to setup a new site / virtual host in CLI command:

```
/bin/bash <( curl -sk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/litespeedtech/ls-cloud-image/master/Setup/vhsetup.sh ) -d www.site2.com -le admin@example.com -f -w
```

- `-le admin@example.com` is for apply Let's encrypt certificate
- `-f` is force to use HTTPS
- `-w` is to auto setup a wordpress

P.S. Please run script with root privileges

Comment: Thank you very much @Eric. I have been trying to follow the Document referred to ( https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/wordpress/#how-do-i-create-additional-virtual-hosts ) . Have followed all the steps and managed to create a directory /usr/local/lsws/site2 and in site2 created directories conf, html, logs. In html have created index.html .

What should I do next to reach index.html when in the browser I type www.site2.com is where I am stumped.  I think I am making a mistake in setting up DNS .

Comment: For setting up DNS however, I have followed exactly the same steps as for site1 which is working correctly. Files for site1 are in folder /var/www/html however. I have managed to migrate a Wordpress site here and it seems to be working fine....

As for now, www.site2.com just takes me to www.site1.com !

All help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So sorry...the document I have been trying to follow is at : https://openlitespeed.org/kb/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting-on-openlitespeed/

Comment: ok, one guess is that you haven't map the www.site2.com domain to specific virtual host. If you have slack, feel free to contact me on the community https://litespeedtech.com/slack and at me Eric , so I can help you faster. Or I need more information, like screenshot the listener and virtual host settings so I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks @Eric !..I  haven't used Slocak before, joined it just now and have sent you messages via :

https://app.slack.com/client/T3RDNH89L/D0169S16MQS

I hope it is you ! If not please respond. Thanks a lot !